# Does this shadow belong to future Marty, trying to get the almanac?

Tags: back-to-the-future, back-to-the-future-ii

In *Back to the Future II*, right when Marty sings "Johnny B. Goode" I spot a shadow in the distance on the right; there's a shadow on the shell.

[image: party with several people]

I thought it was the other Marty trying to get the almanac.

[image: talking into a talkie]

Was that shadow Marty 2, the one trying to get the almanac?

Comment: if you mean the large pink shell to on the far right of the first image, I'd have to say no, it is more likely the shadow of the large deep-sea diver statue

Comment: but were on th eright far right was marty 2

Comment: well....practically speaking the light sources don't make sense for the shadow to be Marty. In the second image, we can see there is no light source bright enough to create a shadow on the side of the shell visible in the first image.

Comment: But what about when Marty 2 looks through the shells to see the dudes to get Marty 1

Comment: It's not his shadow. It can't possibly be. When the first movie was made, the sequel had not yet been planned. According to @Valorum they were not even planning on creating a sequel. If there was no sequel planned, then they would not have been foreshadowing it by placing Marty2 in the first movie.

Comment: But it is the same night same events happineng at the same time

Comment: You are correct. However, time travel isn't actually real and since in real life, the 2nd movie wasn't planned yet, Marty2 could not possibly be in the first movie. Unfortunately, this means you either have to accept that it's an annoying inconsistentcy and move on or come up with something to explain it away like what others have been saying about splitting timelines. Those are your options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No. This is purely coincidental.**

There's no good indication that the makers of the film had any plans to make a sequel, nor did they build any "***[trapdoor foreshadowing](https://theinfosphere.org/Nibbler%27s_shadow)***" into the cinematography on the first film.

Both Zemeckis and Gale have [repeatedly gone on record](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/brian-cronin/did-back-to-the-future-or_b_8344288.html) as saying that it was never their intention to make a BTTF2 (despite the obvious cliffhanger ending). Zemeckis has stated that as proof positive, the way that the film ended was actually something that he regretted when it came time to make the sequels.

> **Q.** *Did you and Bob Zemeckis always know that you wanted to do two sequels? Did you have them mapped out early on?*
>
> **BG:** *No, we had no idea. If you saw the first film in theaters, we never had that “To Be Continued” on there at the end. We added that to
> the VHS tape once we knew we were going to make a sequel. We didn’t
> know if anyone was even going to go see the first one.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Did Back to the Future Originally Not End With ‘To be Continued’?](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/brian-cronin/did-back-to-the-future-or_b_8344288.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: What's trapdoor foreshadowing  ?

Comment: @AndrewCasali - I included an example. It's where the makers of a property intentionally add plot points (minor characters mentioned but not seen, noodle incidents, etc) that they can refer back to in future sequels. Trapdooring also applies to [characters who're integral to the future plotting](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5985727/the-strange-secret-evolution-of-babylon-5), but who might refuse to come back and do a sequel. TV tropes also refers to it as "[Once more with Clarity](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OnceMoreWithClarity)"